# ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx failed to read debuggee

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have write a debugger extension for my VisualStuido2010 to display my class type. I write my code base on the EEAddin sample provided by Microsoft.  But I failed on call ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx.

I can't get any reason for this fail. GetLastError() returns 0.

```
ObjectId objid;
DWORD nGot;
int state = E_FAIL;
if ( pHelper->ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx(pHelper, pHelper->GetRealAddress(pHelper), sizeof(ObjectId), &objid, &nGot) )
{
｝else { log("Fail ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx %d\n", GetLastError());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx(...)` returns a `HRESULT` not a `BOOL`.
Try something like :

```
if (pHelper->ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx(...) == S_OK) {
  // good
｝ else {
  // bad
}
```